# Blank Number field using Extjs

Tags: extjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sZFJ.png)I have 4 columns, namely Quantity, wastage, cost, Final Cost in a grid. at the last row of my grid, I have to show consolidated Final Cost, and nothing else.
My problem is,in last row Quantity, wastage, and Cost column, 0 is shown, whereas in store  data for these column aren't there for last row.

I just want to show empty value on these columns.

data: [{"Name":"Part-0000112-01","Wastage":"4.63","Unit_Cost":"7.00","Quantity":"7.2200","Type":"Fabric","Net_Consumption":"11.8500","totalCost":"82.95"},{"Name":"Part-0000114-01","Wastage":"0.0","Unit_Cost":"1.00","Quantity":"10.0000","Type":"Fabric","Net_Consumption":"10.0000","totalCost":"10.00"},{"Name":"Part-0000116-01","Wastage":"2.0","Unit_Cost":"1.00","Quantity":"10.0000","Type":"Trim","Net_Consumption":"12.0000","totalCost":"12.00",},{"Name":"Part-0000118-01","Wastage":"0.0","Unit_Cost":"0.00","Quantity":"10.0000","Type":"Trim","Net_Consumption":"10.0000","totalCost":"0.00"},{"totalCost":"104.95","Name":"Total Material Costs (InDollar)"}]

Code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {    
    store: BOMStore,    
    columns: [{    
        text: 'Name',    
        dataIndex: 'name'    
    }, {    
        text: 'Quantity',    
        dataIndex: 'Quantity',    
        editor: {    
            xtype : 'numberfield',       
            allowBlank : false,      
            listeners : {    
                change : function(field, newValue,o ,e) {    
                    var quantity = field.value;   
                    var selectedModel = this.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];  
                    var wastage = selectedModel.get('Wastage');  
                    var unitCost = selectedModel.get('Unit_Cost');  
                    var updateTotalCost = getTotalCost(quantity,wastage,unitCost);  
                    selectedModel.set('totalCost', updateTotalCost);  
                    updateRowCosting(selectedModel);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }, {  
        text: 'Wastage',   
        dataIndex: 'Wastage',  
        editor: {  
            xtype : 'numberfield',   
            allowBlank : false,  
        }  
    },{  
        text: 'Cost',  
        dataIndex: 'Unit_Cost',  
        editor: {  
            xtype : 'numberfield',   
            allowBlank : false,  
        }  
    },{  
        text: 'Total Cost',  
        dataIndex: 'totalCost',  
        editor: {  
            xtype : 'numberfield',   
            allowBlank : false,  
        }  
    }]  
});
```

Comment: What you have tried ? post your code as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [renderer](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Column.html#cfg-renderer) which can be used as a converter, so you can check if the row is last one and return empty string.

[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lq9)

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'numm',
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, collIndex, store) {
            if (store.indexOf(record) === (store.totalCount - 1)) {
                return '';
            }
            return value;
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, Quantity is a numberfield. even though i return empty or undefined, the field value is displayed as 0. If i make the field as textfield, then empty is displayed.

Comment: Well, since you edited your post, my code can't be considered as solution. I have couple of questions: 1) what editing plugin are you using, rowediting or cellediting? 2) you said `zeros are shown on the last row`, but i don't see them on the last row(not even while-editing): https://i.imgur.com/wzftLKk.png

Comment: 1) rowediting. 2) if i make the field as textfield, then zeros aren't shown(empty is shown), but if i make it numberfield, then by default it shows 0 even if there is no value.

Comment: take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved.

Below is my model.

```
fields: [ 'Type', 'matid', 'ebomid' , 'srmid' ,'Name', 'Component_Location','Description',
                      'Article','Supplier_Item_Label','Supplier_Item_Description','UOM',
                      { name: 'Quantity', type: 'float' },{ name: 'Wastage', type: 'float' },'Wastage_Percentage','Net_Consumption','Material_Currency','Target_Cost',
                      'markupInViewMode',{ name: 'Markup', type: 'float' },'markup_Percentage','Final_Material_Cost','Sourcing_Classification','Brand_Cost','Vendor_Cost','Total_Cost']
        });
```

So, if I give type float/number in Model, and dont pass the data for corresponding columns, then defaults the value to 0.

We got to set the field type in column.  `xtype : 'numberfield',`